# Get the Sum of checked checkbox for each row of table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, function, checkbox

I want to get the sum total of check box for each row in a table

Javascript : For Sum

```
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() 
      {
            var total = 0;
        $('#mytable tr').each(function()
      {
            total += parseInt($(this).val());    
        $(this).parents('tr').find('input[type=text]:last').val(total);
      }); 
     });
```

Javascript : For Count

```
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
        $('#mytable tr').each(function() {
           var count = $(this).find(':checkbox:checked').length;
         $(this).find('#count').val(count);
       });
       });
```

[image: This is My Result:]

My HTML:

```
               <div class="container">
               <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-2">
                <?php
                    $i=1;
                    $sql="select namefrom
    `student` where EXTRACT(YEAR FROM colRegisteredDate)= 2015";
                    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
                    $data=array();
                ?>
                 <table id="mytable" style="width:100%;">
                    <tr align="center" >
                        <th style="padding:2.5px;
                          width: 10%;" rowspan="2">S.NO</th>
                     <th style="padding:2.5px; 
                          width: 55%;" rowspan="2">StudentID</th>
                     <th style="padding:2.5px;" 
                          colspan="5" style="text-align:center;">subject</th>
                     <th style="padding:2.5px;" rowspan="2">Sum</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                     <th>s1 <input type="checkbox" 
                         id="selectAll" onclick="SelectAll(this)" /></th>
                     <th>s2 <input type="checkbox" 
                         id="selectAll" onclick="SelectAll(this)"/></th>
                     <th>s3 <input type="checkbox" 
                         id="selectAll"onclick="SelectAll(this)" /></th>
                     <th>s4 <input type="checkbox"
                          id="selectAll" onclick="SelectAll(this)" /></th>
                     <th>s5 <input type="checkbox" 
                          id="selectAll" onclick="SelectAll(this)"/></th>
                    </tr>
                        <li>
                           <?php
                              while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                                
                              //$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
                              $data[]=$row['name'];
                              $number=$row['name'];
                              $_SESSION['Roll']=$number;
                              $str = implode("\n", $data);
                              $_SESSION['value']=$number;
                              $_SESSION['url']="index.php?StudentID=$number";
                              ?>
                           <?php
                              ?>
                           <tr>
                              <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                              <td><a href="#" data-id='
                 <?php echo $number; ?>' class="link" id="link">  
                                 <?php
                                    echo  "$number";
                                    ?>
                        </li>
                        </a></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"
               id="a" class="sum" value="10" data-toggle="checkbox"><br></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"
               id="b" class="sum" value="10" data-toggle="checkbox"><br></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"
              id="c" class="sum" value="10" data-toggle="checkbox"><br></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"
              id="d" class="sum" value="10" data-toggle="checkbox"><br></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"
              id="e" class="sum" value="10" data-toggle="checkbox"><br></td>
                        <td><input  type="text" id="total"><br></td>
                        </tr>
                     </table>
                  </div>
                  <?php $i=$i+1; }?>
               </div>
            </div>
```

In the First image when i click Select All ,it shows 1 in paper count and 10 in sum column.
Then,when i click Select All for second time paper count increase in correct way but no change in
sum column.I want to know,How to write for each function .
I want to sum the checked checkbox value when selected indiviually and when select by Select All
Option

**Update**:

I got Half of my result :

```
        $(document).ready(function()
      {  
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function()
      {
               var total=0;
        $(this).parents("tr").children("td").
          find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(){ 
                total +=parseInt($(this).val());
        $(this).parents('tr').find('input[type=text]:last').val(total);
      });
      });
      });
```

Now the Only Problem is the above code Not sum the row value ,when i Click Select All.Any Help For this issue?

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/suryaa/m8yts6ow/37/)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: the value are in a string type, you ave to converse to numéric value

Comment: It will help people to answer faster, if you create a js fiddle, or add your html in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(this).parents("tr").children("td").find('input[type=checkbox]:checked')
```

When you tick the `checkall` checkbox, it will be matched by this selector. It doesn't have an explicit `value` set, so `.val()` will return the string `"on"`.

Obviously, the string `"on"` cannot be converted to an integer, so your `total` will become `NaN`.

Exclude the `.checkall` checkbox from your selector, and your code will work.

```
$(this).parents('tr').find(':checkbox:checked').not(".checkall").each(...
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RichardD/37ag1q8b/)

**NB:** You should also pay attention to [the jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) - `$(document).ready(fn)` has been deprecated since v3. Use `$(fn)` instead.

---

**Edit:** Based on your [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/suryaa/m8yts6ow/37/) posted on [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5289403/Get-the-sum-of-checked-checkbox-for-each-row-of-ta), you just need to trigger the `change` event of your checkbox after you've updated it from the `SelectAll` function:

```
table.find('td:nth-child(' + columnIndex + ') input').prop("checked", obj.checked).change();
```

[Fixed updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RichardD/mv4uypgt/)

Comment: Thank You Soo Much For Your Help, This is what i tried to do.